# Initialize array in function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

When I want to initialize a pointer to an array through the function, I am doing the following:

Initialize and destroy array through functions:

```
int initArr(int **b)
{
    int *arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*2);

    if(arr == NULL)
        return 0;

    *b = arr;
    arr = NULL;
    return 1;
}

void destroyArr(int *b)
{
    free(b); 
    b = NULL;
}
```

Initialize pointer to array:

```
int *pArr;
int initStatus = initArr(&pArr);

if(initStatus == 0)
{
    printf("%s", "error");
    return 0;
}
```

Working with pointer to array:

```
*pArr = 1;
*(pArr + 1) = 2;

printf("0 = %i\n", *pArr);
printf("1 = %i\n", *(pArr + 1));
```

Destroy pointer to array:

```
destroyArr(pArr);
pArr = NULL;
```

Is this correct and safe?

Comment: I see no flaw in your approach.  Good work.

Comment: Most people find `pArr[1] = 2;` easier to read than your `*(pArr + 1) = 2;`. They are equivalent.

Comment: In C, usually success is indicated by 0, and non-zero is a kind of failure. The call to malloc will return NULL or a valid address, but standard fare is the function that does that would normally return 0 for success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but it appears correct. A minor comment, though: you don't need to set `arr` or `b` to `NULL`, they're at the very end of their scope and can't be (safely) accessed after that anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The initArr function can be reduced to:

```
int initArr(int **b)
{
    *b = malloc(2 * sizeof **b);

    return *b ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In fact, initArr and destroyArr do not add any value at all.
They wrap the standard C functions to return and do the exact same thing.

Also, you could use array indexers [] to access individual members of the allocated array.

Here is a working equivalent:

```
int* pArr = (int*) malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
if (pArr) {
    pArr[0] = 1;
    pArr[1] = 2;
    printf("0 = %d\n", pArr[0]);
    printf("1 = %d\n", pArr[1]);
    free(pArr);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks good but the `free` in `destroyArr()` does not give you anything since you are not passing a double pointer to it.

Comment: Actually it does. Setting it to `NULL` doesn't affect the variable in the calling function but `b` does point to the memory intended to be freed and so frees it properly.