# C pointers and malloc confusion EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, exc-bad-access

So today's exercise is to  create a function to `initialize an array of int` and `fill it` from 0 to n.

I wrote this :

```
void        function(int **array, int max)
{
    int i = 0;
    *array = (int *) malloc((max + 1) * sizeof(int));
    while (i++ < max)
    {
        *array[i - 1] = i - 1; // And get EXC_BAD_ACCESS here after i = 2
    }
}
```

After a few hours of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` I was getting crazy I decided to search on SO, find this question : [Initialize array in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870891/initialize-array-in-function)
Then changed my function to :

```
void        function(int **array, int max)
{
    int *ptr; // Create pointer
    int i = 0;
    ptr = (int *) malloc((max + 1) * sizeof(int)); // Changed to malloc to the fresh ptr
    *array = ptr; // assign the ptr
    while (i++ < max)
    {
        ptr[i - 1] = i - 1; // Use the ptr instead of *array and now it works
    }
}
```

And now it works ! But it's not enough to have it working, I would really like to know why my first approach didn't work ! To me they look the same !

PS : just in case this is the main I use :

```
int main() {
    int *ptr = NULL;
    function(&ptr, 9);
    while (*ptr++) {
        printf("%d", *(ptr - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't yet ! Don't worry Ill do it as soon as I can : 9 more mins

Comment: My bad!...I am sorry!

Comment: @ItsASecret I would also suggest not using null-terminated array for integers. It can easily lead to runtime errors

Comment: Where do you see it being null terminated :/ ?

Comment: @TaylorFlores, its not a null-terminated array but a pointer initialized to NULL

Comment: @ItsASecret it looks like that's how you're traversing it in your `while` loop

Comment: Oh I get it now, you mean the loop in the main with while(*ptr++) it was just a quick ugly code to test if the array was filled or not, sorry for not being clear the first time ! Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: @ItsASecret it also looks like a null-terminated array because of the `max + 1` in your allocation. It's not really that important in test code, but I've noticed that people really don't like it in complete programs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the wrong precedence,

```
*array[i - 1] = i - 1;
```

should be

```
(*array)[i - 1] = i - 1;
```

Without the parentheses, you access

```
*(array[i-1])
```

or `array[i-1][0]`, which is not allocated for `i > 1`.